# Angular Route not working. Single page application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in the middle of creating a mini spa  in my MVC application
I have configured my angular route but it doesn't seem working. When I type http://localhost:81/Registration/ on the browser address bar,the registation index page does get rendered. Also when I click on the hyperlinks to browse for the course and instructors, it does render accordingly. But for some reason the data doesnt render.  When I do View Source, I see the following error.

```
A public action method &#39;Courses&#39; was not found on controller &#39;AngularJSMvcExample.Controllers.RegistrationController&#39;.
```

I feel MVC route is taking precedence. Why is it looking for Courses action method in the registrationController. The registration controller has only index method.

Following is my code

registrationModule

```
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", [])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Courses', { templateUrl: '/templates/courses.html', controller: 'CoursesController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Instructors', { templateUrl: '/templates/instructors.html', controller: 'InstructorsController' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Index view which the MVC Registration controller calls. It contains two links to Browse which should call the relevant angular view and display it in the ng-view section below.

```
@model AngularJSMvcExample.Models.RegistrationVm

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registration";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section JavascriptInHead {

    <script src="~/Scripts/courses/courses-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/instructors/instructors-controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    registrationModule.factory('bootstrappedData', function() {
        return {
            courses:  @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Courses).Replace("'","")),
            instructors:  @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Instructors).Replace("'",""))
            };

    });
</script>

}



<div class="container">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <span class="navbar-brand">Registration</span>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav nav-bar">
                    <li> <span class="navbar-brand"><a href="/Registration/Courses">Browse Catalog</a></span></li>
                    <li> <span class="navbar-brand"><a href="/Registration/Instructors">Browse Instructors</a></span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

The angular Courses view which is in an html page that needs to rendered in the ng-view section above

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Instructor</th>

            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="course in courses">
                <td>{{course.number}}</td>
                <td>{{course.name}}</td>
                <td>{{course.instructor}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The angular Instructor view which is in an html page that needs to rendered in the ng-view section above

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Room No</th>

            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="instructor in instructors">
                <td>{{instructor.name}}</td>
                <td>{{instructor.email}}</td>
                <td>{{instructor.roomno}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something wrong with your server configuration to allow using html5Mode. Server needs to be aware that you are using virtual directories in angular routing or you need to switch back to default hash based routing

Comment: Could you give me an example to understand better

Comment: I don't work with IIS hardly at all. Did you do any configuration in web.config for html5mode? If not should be easy to search for how to set it up. To be honest I don't know why you even use a server side framework to deliver angular templates either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> http://localhost:81/Registration/

Needs to be http://localhost:81/#/Registration to fit within the guides of AngularJS. This it to fit with cross compatibility in older browsers. You can override this by adding a base href tag between your head tags. You will also need to add this

> $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

To your app config for AngularJS To know it is supposed to run in HTML5 mode allowing you to use routes without the # sign.

Caution though in testing when using HTML5 in AngularJS apps, there are quirks that will come with doing so. Your route file may now need to have the /#/route to navigate properly as using HTML5 mode in AngularJS really simply spoofs the address bar and still internally uses the # sign.